# Is it possible to move /copy artboard to other file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to move /copy artboard to other file in illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste content from the artboard. Alternatively when saving the file in Illustrator, check "Save each artboard to a separate file." Hope this will help.

[image]

Comment: Then what? How do you get it into another file while preserving layers?