# Move artboards between files

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'd like to know if it's possible move artboards, with their contents, across open *.ai files.

I have two *.ai files, each with two artboards. I'd like to move two of the artboards from one file to the other, effectively merging the two files into one (I'll delete the empty one). This is useful to minimize the number of different *.ai files I have, sorting them by content type and making use of the artboard mechanism that works so wonderfully.

I've [read](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57037/is-it-possible-to-move-copy-artboard-to-other-file) that it's possible to save each artboard into a separate files (opposite of what I want).

I also know I can copy and paste the contents of an artboard (which is what I've been doing), but it would be cleaner to just move the artboard as a whole.

Is it really only possible through [script](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/954411)?

Comment: You cannot copy /paste the artboard. Instead of copy/paste the objects, you can go to Window>>arrange>>tile. Now you can simply drag the objects from one doc to another.

Comment: Yes, only through Script, where the Artboard name and object inside will transfer to a New Document file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, yes, Copy/Paste or the script (which copy/pastes for you) are currently the only options.

Comment: I can't make it work for me in Illustrator CC

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now in Illustrator 2020.

Select the artboard tool, then (on mac) hold down shift and drag over the artboards you wish to select.

You can then copy and paste or simply drag them to the other document and it will copy the artboards with their content over.